# Is it possible to turn on/include Execution Log into Debug Logs in Salesforce?

Tags: debugging

**Is it possible to include Developer Console/Execution Log into Monitor/Debug Logs in Salesforce**?

I mean that very Execution Log that is in Developer Console. I need that *verbose* logging for day or two on production system.

Comment: you can enable debug logs for 6 hours max in time. If you need something more stable -- build custom logging system that would create log records (sObjects) when needed

Comment: @Ratan correct, 12 hours

Comment: @kurunve Sorry not 12 hrs.. that is 24 hrs max..